# In a DialogFragment, what should onCreate do?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am currently messing around with DialogFragment to learn to use it. I assumed that compared to `onCreateView()`, `onCreate()` can do this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    testTextView.setText("SUCCESS!"); //ERROR HERE
}
```

But I am wrong. Not sure why its not working. The error goes away when I comment out `testTextView.setText("Success!");`
The error is a NullPointerException, and then it just flags line 39 which is where the offending line of code is. Any clarifications much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View testView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog_file, container, false);
    //instantiated testTextView globally
    testTextView = (TextView)testView.findViewById(R.id.set_text);
    testTextView.setText("SUCCESS!");
    return testView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

testTextView is NOT pointing to any object so try something like

```
testTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
```

**EDIT:**

If you see the [lifecycle of a fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle), it says that `onCreateView` is called *after* `onCreate` hence your `onCreate` doesn't have any reference to your object, that is textview in your layout

Comment: I do have one quick question that the Doc does not say. In DialogFragments, do I need to use `onAttach()`? And I will, except it doesn't let me until a certain time has passed lol.

Comment: if you want to you can use `onAttach()` but you don't need it in your case.

Comment: `onAttach` should be used so that you can do some `init()` for your fragment but in your case its a simple laying out a view and trying to get a reference which you should do in your 'onCreate' method

Answer (score 2):

You haven't used `setContentView` yet, so you are getting a NPE for the TextView.

`onCreate` happens before `onCreateView`.  If you want to access something from the layout there, you need to `setContentView`... which is not a good idea for a DialogFragment.

Move that bit of code to `onCreateView` after you `setContentView` and you'll be ok.

For your reference, here's the Fragment Lifecycle:

[image]

Comment: Ahh. Since you have this great diagram here, I might as well ask, `onAttach()`, should I use it on a DialogFragment?

Comment: Honestly, I've never used `onAttach`, so I don't really know... I'm trying to think what you might use it for... nothing UI related obviously.  :)

Comment: Haha. Indeed. Was curious, covering all basics. Doesn't look like anybody uses it in tutorials. Was wondering why. Thanks.

Comment: OnAttach() is usually used for attaching listeners to the parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the testTextView in onCreateView? You have to use a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) in onCreateView to get the Layout and then you have to access the TextView via findViewById.

Comment: Yes sir. Did that. I will post that code. As you can see, the error is strange as I would assume I could `setText`

Comment: Not strange at all as `onCreateView` occurs **after** `onCreate`.