# When to stop an AsyncTask in a retained DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I'm using a **retained** `DialogFragment` which display a progression dialog during a TCP connection executed in an `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` is executed in the fragmebt's `onStart()` method, and cancelled either when the `DialogFragment` is cancelled, or in the fragment's `onStop()` method.

When my task finished (i.e, tcp connection is established or failed), or is cancelled, I dismiss the dialog using the `dismiss()` method.

The problem is when I press "Home" when the AsyncTask is running. In this case the fragment `onStop()` method is called, which cancels the AsyncTask, and try to dismiss the dialog, but then I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

I saw there is a method named [dismissAllowingStateLoss()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismissAllowingStateLoss()) which will avoid this exception but I'm not sure it's the best solution, I don't want it to "hide" an issue.

The expected behavior is the following: if the user leaves the activity, I want to cancel the connection, that's why I stop it in `onStop()`.

Here is the Fragment code for reference :

```
public class TcpConnectionFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpConnectionFragment.class);

    private TcpConnectionTask connectionTask;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public static TcpConnectionFragment newInstance(String host, int port) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ADDRESS", host);
        bundle.putInt("PORT", port);
        TcpConnectionFragment fragment = new TcpConnectionFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void startAsyncTask() {
        logger.info("Starting asynchronous connection task");
        connectionTask = new TcpConnectionTask(this, host, port);
        connectionTask.execute();
    }

    private void stopAsyncTask() {
        if (connectionTask == null)
            return;
        logger.info("Stopping asynchronous connection task");
        connectionTask.cancel(false);
        try {
            SocketChannel channel = connectionTask.getSocketChannel();
            if (channel != null)
                channel.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            // We don't care about this error here, we can't recover.
        }
    }

    public TcpConnectionFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        if (getArguments() == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing arguments");
        host = getArguments().getString("ADDRESS");
        port = getArguments().getInt("PORT");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new MaterialDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .title(R.string.tcp_connect_dialog_title)
            .content(R.string.tcp_connect_dialog_text, host, port)
            .progress(true, 0)
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        startAsyncTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopAsyncTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        logger.info("Cancelled dialog.");
        stopAsyncTask();
    }

    /**
     * This override is required to avoid a bug in the support library.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
            getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    /**
     * Called by the {@link TcpConnectionTask} once connected.
     *
     * @param transport The transport created during the conenction.
     */
    void onConnected(Transport transport) {
        connectionTask = null;
        dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Called by the {@link TcpConnectionTask} once the connection is cancelled.
     */
    void onConnectionCancelled() {
        connectionTask = null;
        dismiss();
    }

    /*
     * Called by the {@link TcpConnectionTask} if an error occurs during the connection.
     */
    void onConnectionError(Exception error) {
        connectionTask = null;
        dismiss();
        if (getParentFragment() == null || getParentFragment().getView() == null)
            return;
        Snackbar.make(getParentFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.frame_layout),
                "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call dismiss from onPause() instead. That should do it.

Check out the DialogFragment diagram from this thread:
[In a DialogFragment, what should onCreate do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046075/in-a-dialogfragment-what-should-oncreate-do)

Example on cancellation callback:

```
mCancelObj = new CancellationObject();
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {    
  // do something
  // whenFinished check if !mCancelObj.isCancelled -> dialog.dismiss();
}.execute(); 

void onPause(){
mCancelObj.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Currently I call dismiss() from AsyncTask callbacks, which means I dismiss() the dialog when te connection has been established, cancelled or an error occurred. If I do it in onPause(), it will work for the pause case, but I might still have issues for example if the task is finished the same time the user press Home, no ?

Comment: In that case I would pass on a cancellation object that can be cancelled from within the asynctask, so that it is possible to do some cleanup in case the fragment stops. I use Bolts Tasks which is an awesome library for running async task with cancellation objetcs.  Check it out here, if you dont already know it: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Comment: There is no way to check if the fragment is in a "valid" state in the callback ? To check if dismiss() can be called safely ? If I can avoid using a huge library it would be good :-)

Comment: I'll write an examle in my answer above, how I think a solution could look like..